# How to print wireless on a receipt printers (Epson TM) with java?

Tags: java, printing, wireless, javapos, receipt

i need to write a Java application that is capable of printing wirelessly on an Epson TM receipt printer. I researched quite a while and came across with Java POS drivers, but I am not sure if they actually support wireless printing or not. Also it seems, that receipt printers don´t work with the standard Java printer API?

If anyone could give me some advise or hint, i would be more then thankful

Comment: You need hardware support. Taking a look at the website I see this. http://pos.epson.com/products/prodsPMOP.htm?ProductPK=492

Comment: @TJR, your link is 404.

Comment: @james, sorry. That was a bad choice to link to epson.com :( Back in 2011, when it was posted it worked...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write Java on Android, you can download the Android SDK from Epson after registering. Then you can use the API calls to send your strings to the printer. The printers, such as TM 88 III and IV come with USB, LAN, or Wireless interfaces.

The SDK come with a demo Android app which you can run in Emulator or on a device, and has some handy functions such as below:

```
    m_Device.printString("Print a String to the printer", FONT.FONT_A, true, false, true, true);
    m_Device.sendCommand("FS p 2 0"); // Code the cut the pape
    m_Device.sendCommand("FS p 1 0"); // Code to print out the NV Ram Logo stored in the printer
```